# quicker way to load json

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have website logs saved as json, and I want to load them in pandas.
I have this kind of json structure, with multiple nested data :

```
{"settings":{"siteIdentifier":"site1"},
    "event":{"name":"pageview",
             "properties":[]},
    "context":{"date":"Thu Dec 01 2016 01:00:08 GMT+0100 (CET)",
               "location":{"hash":"",
                           "host":"aaa"},
               "screen":{"availHeight":876,
                         "orientation":{"angle":0,
                                        "type":"landscape-primary"}},
               "navigator":{"appCodeName":"Mozilla",
                            "vendorSub":""},
               "visitor":{"id": "unique_id"}},
    "server":{"HTTP_COOKIE":"uid",
              "date":"2016-12-01T00:00:09+00:00"}}
{"settings":{"siteIdentifier":"site2"},
    "event":{"name":"pageview",
             "properties":[]},
    "context":{"date":"Thu Dec 01 2016 01:00:10 GMT+0100 (CET)",
               "location":{"hash":"",
                           "host":"aaa"},
               "screen":{"availHeight":852,
                         "orientation":{"angle":90,
                                        "type":"landscape-primary"}},
               "navigator":{"appCodeName":"Mozilla",
                            "vendorSub":""},
               "visitor":{"id": "unique_id"}},
    "server":{"HTTP_COOKIE":"uid",
              "date":"2016-12-01T00:00:09+00:10"}}
```

The only working solution for now is :

```
import pandas as pd
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', False)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 10)
pd.set_option("display.max_rows",30)

first = True
filename = "/path/to/file.json"
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f: # read line by line to retrieve only one json
        data = json.loads(line) # convert single json from string to json
        if first: # initialize the dataframe
            df = json_normalize(data)
            first = False
        else: # add a row for each json
            df=df.append(json_normalize(data)) #normalize to flatten the data
df.to_csv("2016-12-02.csv",index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

I have to read line by line because my jsons are just pasted one after the other and not in a list. My code is working but it is very very slow.
What can I do to improve it? I use pandas because it seems appropriate, but if there is another way it's ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put all the JSON objects into a single iterable first:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    data = [json.loads(line) for line in f]
    df = json_normalize(data)
df.to_csv("2016-12-02.csv",index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: I get an error on 'df = json_normalize(data)' : "TypeError: 'generator' object has no attribute '__getitem__'"

Comment: @HarryPotfleur ok, wasn't sure what would happen since I don't use pandas so I wanted to try the slightly more efficient option first. I edited it, it's now square brackets indicating a list comprehension instead of a generator.

Comment: I just tested it, it's amazingly faster! thanks a lot!